# A form with one field that counts the times a value has been entered

Tags: php, forms

I need a simple form with one field that saves the input on my SQL database. Then I want to be get a list of the things that have been submitted ordered by the number of times they have been submitted. I don't how to make the form do this.

I'm not sure if it's clear, If not please leave a comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Saves 'what has been typed' *where*? A 'list of the things that have been entered' *by whom*, and *from where*?

Comment: I want to save what has been typed on the single field on my database like a normal form and then I want to get all things entered by my users ordered by the number of times each value has been entered. I'm not quite sure if that's what you asked. If not please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple question with a simple answer. It seems that there are several things that you need to learn in order to accomplish what you ask. A google search for PHP SQL tutorials will bring up a long list of websites that offer suggestions. [Like this one](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql).

I would suggest that you start with a tutorial like that and take it step at a time. When you run into problems you can ask here about the specific problem.

Saving the values entered into the form in a database is not difficult. Your logic will have to take into consideration that the value may already exist. You will need a table like this:

```
   terms = (word, wordcount)
```

where wordcount is the number of times the word was entered. When a user enters a value you will:

1. get the value
2. query the table for the value
3. if found, update wordcount = wordcount + 1
4. else insert the word and a count of 1.