# How do I make my search form save every search on a database?

Tags: php, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A form with one field that counts the times a value has been entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481035/a-form-with-one-field-that-counts-the-times-a-value-has-been-entered)

I need to make my search form save every value that it's entered, and then I want to be able to retrieve the values ordered by the number of times they have been searched, but I have no idea how.

This is my search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="http://chusmix.com/" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s').value.length < 4) return false;" style="float:right; display:inline; padding-right:10px;">
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

I have an SQL database I know that's important... I know little of PHP but if there is any info you may need please ask me and if possible tell me where to get it.

Comment: Do you have *any* idea how to work with databases in PHP?

Comment: This is the **third** time you've posted this question.  Repeatedly asking the same thing will not get you better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this isn't too complex a problem, thinking through it you need to go through the following:

1. Upon submit of the form, your php processing page should validate the input (no code injection), then do an `INSERT` into the table of choice (ex: searchterms).
2. Next you would run your normal search results.
3. In order to show a count of the number of 'repeat' search terms you can run a query like below (I am assuming you are using mysql)

Get a count of search results:

`SELECT term, count(term)
FROM searchterms
GROUP BY term`

Overall you will need to learn the following to accomplish this (I am assuming you are VERY new to PHP).

1. Learn how to process PHP form information (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
2. Learn how to access MYSQL databases using PHP (http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert.asp)
3. Displaying mysql results using PHP (http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/retrieve-data-from-a-mysql-database.aspx)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks I'll read all those tutorials and try again. I just needed someone to point me in the right direction.